# View is not loading after renaming the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I changed my controller from `homecontroller` to `ProfileController`.
Now my view is not showing anything, but when I changed it back from `Profilecontroller` to `homecontroller` it works fine again.

I also changed:

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("index", "homeController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

to:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("index", "ProfileController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the view explicitly in the controller action, then MVC uses a convention for the view lookup `/Views/<ControllerName>/<ActionName>.cshtml`:

```
/Views/Profile/Index.cshtml
```

In your case you have to rename the folder `Home` to `Profile` too.

Additional information from the documentation:
 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller
 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view

Comment: Thanks to help me in this case
Dear I did not change folder name I changed only controller name
in Controller
 Online_ShoppingEntities entities = new Online_ShoppingEntities();
            entities.COMPANies.Add(new COMPANY
            {
                Image = fileName,
                path = filePath
            });
            entities.SaveChanges();

            //Redirect to Index Action.
            return RedirectToAction("index");
to I changed

Comment: @AbdulJabbar Yes. That's the problem. Where is your Index.cshtml located? I guess in `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` => so if you rename `Home` to `Profile` MVC can find your view again.

Comment: In folder View/Home/

Comment: @AbdulJabbar You have to rename the folder. New structure should be `View/Profile/Index.cshtml`.

Comment: No dear I did not rename a folder

Comment: I rename only contoller name then rename homecontlloer to profilecontroller
then I rename index.cshtml to profile.cshtml afte then I changed
return RedirectToAction("index"); to return RedirectToAction("Profile");
Now when I run program view display nothing

Comment: thanks a lot i resloved this issue with change acction result index to profile
now when I changed my Controller name then i got thiss error 
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'